# Best way to store large 2d array of type float

Tags: c#, sql-server, acoustics

I am currently working on an acoustic analysis project which is being written in C#.

Having been able to correctly calculate the feature for the wav file selected by the user, I am now moving onto template matching which will be used to identify key events within the wav file selected by the user.

As part of this next step, I will be reading in wav files, calculating the feature for those wav files and I will have to store the results of the feature calculation.

The 2d arrays created by this are generally of size, for example, `array[1800][30]` and these values will need saved.

My question is what would you suggest is the best method of storing an array of this scale so that the values within it can be read later when comparing the feature generated (array) for a user selected wav file, with the values of the saved array.

The more arrays that I save in order to compare with the currently selected wav file, the greater the accuracy of the template matching. So it is possible that i could have `> 100` arrays of size `array[1800][30]`, which need saved.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: have you considered a database solution

Comment: You will certainly want to store such large files in binary form, probably with some kind of fixed-size header at the front containing metadata about the file, such as file format version, number of rows and cols and so on. What sort of level are your File IO and Serialization skills?

Comment: You first need to ask yourself what kinds of questions are you going to be asking the database to answer, which may have a lot to do with the meaning of these 1800x30 floats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Serialization** to save any object from RAM (random access memory) to Hard Disk. 
In serialization process any *serializable* object can be converted in to byte streams, this byte streams can be stored in files or data base.
The reversal operation is called **DeSerialization**. 
[Serialization basic concepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx)
[.NET and Object Serialization using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1789/Object-Serialization-using-C)
[Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)

Comment: Your first 2 links go to the same location.

Comment: Thanks M.Heydari, i will give these resources a read, this sounds like the type of operation that i would like to perform.